# Visual Studio 2010 workflow designer Shows Build Tasks Without  Borders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm having a display problem with the TFS build workflow visualizer in Visual Studio 2010.

Steps to reproduce:
1) Run devenv /safemode
2) Open DefaultTemplate.xaml from source control. (Mine has not been modified since TFS created the project)

Expected behavior: All tasks displayed with border
Actual behavior: Only the currently selected task has borders displayed

I've never used the build workflow editor on this machine so I have no idea if it ever worked.
ReSharper 6.0 was installed recently, but I uninstalled it and it had no effect.

Has anybody else seen behavior like this? Or know how to fix it?

Environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Ultimate
Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Architecture and Modeling Tools   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis Spell Checker   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01019-532-2002102-70357
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01019-532-2002102-70357
Coded UI Test Editor   1.0
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2522890)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2529927)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2547352)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2548139)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2549864)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU (KB2565057)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack 2.0
NuGet Package Manager   1.5.20902.9026
Theme Manager   1.0
Package for managing Visual Studio color schemes

Comment: What are your systems hardware specs? Is this a VM?

Comment: Well as I experienced this happens only if you have the Windows Aero theme enabled.
That one has the background color for the borders as white.
I also like Aero. :-(
I also tried to play around with the Workflow Color Editor, but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

It's more involved than this.
After much googling and trying, I managed to get the flow to render correctly by:

1. setting the default theme in the "Visual Studio Color Theme Editor" Theme menu.
2. disabling the extension and restarting VS
3. -at this point the flow is displayed as it should -
4. enabling the extension again
5. setting my theme again (and thus getting rid of the "punch in my eye" default color scheme.

The problems now is that as soon as I restart VS again, I'm back to square one, i.e. no borders.

Answer (score 0):

> Package for managing Visual Studio color schemes

I had the same problem.  It went away when I disabled the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor extension.